# php multidimensional array to get value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am going crazy with this one how do I do a foreach to echo return the slug values.

this is my array : `[{"id":1,"catid":"digital-art","scategory":"3-Dimensional Art","slug":"3-dimensional-art","created_at":"2014-01-29 12:17:21","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]`

print_r returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [catid] => digital-art
            [scategory] => 3-Dimensional Art
            [slug] => 3-dimensional-art
            [created_at] => 2014-01-29 12:17:21
            [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you parse it using json_decode?

Comment: no I did not, its within a class and once i use json decode it returns an error. I just did a print r I updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an "array" but a JSON fromatted String. You my parse this into an array with

```
$myArray = json_decode('[{"id":1,"catid":"digital-art","scategory":"3-Dimensional Art","slug":"3-dimensional-art","created_at":"2014-01-29 12:17:21","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]', true);
```

Where the last parameter will indicate to convert this in to an associative array as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [catid] => digital-art
            [scategory] => 3-Dimensional Art
            [slug] => 3-dimensional-art
            [created_at] => 2014-01-29 12:17:21
            [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )

)
```

And this will iterate

```
foreach ( $myArray[0] as $key => $value ) { ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated per your new comment:

According to your new `print_r`, your data is already in a JSON object format so no need to parse it again (`jsode_decode()` will fail).

Assuming your object's name is `$data`, you can access its data by:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
            echo $item->{'slug'};
            echo $item->slug;//same thing
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you i ve been pulling my hair it returns an error whenever I do the decode!

Comment: Yeah I feel you...json_decode will only work on a string that you want to convert to an object. When dealing with JSON, always do a var_dump/print_r to see the data type.

Comment: @fogsy the answer you marked as correct is NOT the correct answer, as json_decode() will fail.